# Azure AD Authentication Token Generation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for authentication . On successful authentication, I receive a token from AuthentictaionResult. Instead of using the same token to query the Graph Api,I am generating a new token from Azure AD Graph api and querying with it. Is this approach correct or should I query Azure AD Graph API with same token obtained from AuthentictaionResult? Please advise

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're doing inside the successful authentication? Is it requesting access to any resource or just doing sign in?

Comment: Requests sent to the Graph API must be well-formed, target a valid endpoint and version of the Graph API, and carry a valid access token obtained from Azure AD in their Authorization header. Refer: [Operations overview | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview)

Comment: @Daniel Dobalian After signing in i'm querying the Graph api to obtain logged in user details and tenant details to use those in my application